# How to calculate the exponential in some columns of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, exponential

I have a dataframe:

```
X   Year    Dependent.variable.1    Forecast.Dependent.variable.1
1   2009    12.42669703             12.41831191
2   2010    12.39309563             12.40043599
3   2011    12.36596964             12.38256006
4   2012    12.32067284             12.36468414
5   2013    12.303095               12.34680822
6   2014    NA                      12.32893229
7   2015    NA                      12.31105637
8   2016    NA                      12.29318044
9   2017    NA                      12.27530452
10  2018    NA                      12.25742859
```

I want to calulate the exponential of the third and fourth columns. How can I do that?

Comment: Full disclosure: I'm not sure on this technology, but fundamentally, you need to wrap your code in backticks or put it in a code block.  It would also be helpful to users looking to answer the question if you could show what you have tried so far.  Thanks!

Comment: @Thais: I added an answer below. Please let me know whether that answers your question and if not, in which way it should be revised. If it answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the check next to my answer (which then turns green). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your dataframe is called `dfs`, you can do the following:

```
dfs[c('Dependent.variable.1','Forecast.Dependent.variable.1')] <- exp(dfs[c('Dependent.variable.1','Forecast.Dependent.variable.1')])
```

which gives you:

```
    X Year Dependent.variable.1 Forecast.Dependent.variable.1
1   1 2009               249371                      247288.7
2   2 2010               241131                      242907.5
3   3 2011               234678                      238603.9
4   4 2012               224285                      234376.5
5   5 2013               220377                      230224.0
6   6 2014                   NA                      226145.1
7   7 2015                   NA                      222138.5
8   8 2016                   NA                      218202.9
9   9 2017                   NA                      214336.9
10 10 2018                   NA                      210539.5
```

In case you know the column numbers, this could then also simply be done by using:

```
dfs[,3:4] <- exp(dfs[,3:4])
```

which gives you the same result as above. I usually prefer to use the actual column names as the indices might change when the data frame is further processed (e.g. I delete columns, then the indices change).

Or you could do:

```
dfs$Dependent.variable.1 <- exp(dfs$Dependent.variable.1)
dfs$Forecast.Dependent.variable.1 <- exp(dfs$Forecast.Dependent.variable.1)
```

In case you want to store these columns in new variables (below they are called `exp1` and `exp2`, respectively), you can do:

```
exp1 <- exp(dfs$Forecast.Dependent.variable.1)
exp2 <- exp(dfs$Dependent.variable.1)
```

In case you want to apply it to more than two columns and/or use more complicated functions, I highly recommend to look at [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html)/[lappy](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Just to be clear, if you want to do this with less code and you know the column numbers (as you stated in the question), then `dfs[,3:4] <- exp(dfs[,3:4])` would suffice.